# How to set default class property value with a variable from another php file?

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a website. 
 
I'm coding the server side with PHP and SQL on a WAMP Server. 
At the moment I'm trying to build bases classes, other classes will be based upon.

This is the [diagram](http://www.plcs.org/plcslib/plcslib/data/PLCS/psm_model/images/SysML_Block_Definition_Diagram__Diagrams__Identification.png) what I'm trying to implement.

I would like also that some business object properties be set with value from a business dictionary : ReferenceData.php (later definitions will be at the end in ReferenceData.xml). In the following class it is done at line 24:

> private $role = $classif_identifier;

but this line is faulty at runtime

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\Wampee-3.1.0-beta-3.4\www\HTML_PHP_Training\PHP OO\Identifier.php on line 24*

Why?
Identification.php is like this :

```
<?php
include 'ReferenceData.php';
class Identifier
{
    //idString [1] : IdentifierString: the alphanumeric string that represents an identifying name or code.
    private $idString;

    //role [1] : ClassSelect the classification that defines the role of the identification. The possible classifications are subclasses of http://docs.oasis-open.org/plcs/ns/plcslib/v1.0/data/plcs/plcs-psm/refdata/plcs-psm#Identifier
    private $role = $classif_identifier;

    /*  Constraint: UR1
    Specification: (OCL2.0)
    Identifier::allInstances()->isUnique(Sequence{idString, role, identificationContext}) */

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->idString = $id;
    }
    public function get_idString()
    {
        return $this->idString;
    }
    public function set_idString($id)
    {
        $this->idString = $id;
    }
    public function get_role()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
    public function set_role($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }
}
?>
```

And $classif_identifier is defined is ReferenceData.php which is like this :

```
<?php
/* Class URI:   http://docs.oasis-open.org/plcs/ns/plcslib/v1.0/data/plcs/plcs-psm/refdata/plcs-psm#Identifier
Class label: identifier
Definition:
name or code that is used to label something and to refer to that thing */

$classif_identifier='http://docs.oasis-open.org/plcs/ns/plcslib/v1.0/data/plcs/plcs-psm/refdata/plcs-psm#Identifier';
?>
```

Both files are in the same folder.

Do you know how to do that? What's wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the constructor, like:

```php
public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->idString = $id;

    global $classif_identifier;
    $this->role = $classif_identifier;
}
```

> **Note:** if the variable defined in another file is in global scope you have to tell PHP exactly that, like "`global $classif_identifier;`".

Another way to do it would be:

```php
<?php
include 'ReferenceData.php';

// Below is what your code is missing:
global $classif_identifier;

class Identifier
{
    // ...

    private $role = $classif_identifier;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested in the first way in the constructor. Yes I hadn't realize it has related to 'global' keyword. Thank you Top-Master!